# read a txt file line by line in C

Tags: c, char, cs50, fread

I'm trying to retract strings from a txt file.

The file content is;

1. apple
2. pear
3. orange

basicly every line has one word and I would like to read every line and retract words into the string `char* word[25]` because the longer word is 24 characters. When I implement a simple code to read every character in ASCII between each line there was value `10` for end of line. So I created a `for` loop without any condition and added `if` condition to spot the `10` value end of line (LF). But it doesn't work and I'm sure I messed in something very basic in code or logic. Sorry if my code seems unlogical or very wrong, I'm fairly new. Also there are lots of libraries added cos I'm going to use them if I could done this step. TIA

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./word filename\n");

        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE* ptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    char ch;
    char* word[45];
    
    for (int i = 0; ;i++)
    {
        ch = fgetc(ptr);
        
        word[i] = &ch;
        
        if (ch == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", *word);

    return 0;
}
```

terminal output

```
~/snippets/ $ make word
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    word.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o word
~/snippets/ $ ./word lec3.txt

`
 ~/snippets/ $
```

Comment: `char* word[45];` is not for a _string_.  That is 45 pointers.  Perhaps you want `char word[3][45];` to read/store 3 lines into strings of max length 44?

Comment: Can't you use `fgets()`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks for the tip, you're right. I fixed it but still can't read the whole first line. I think I made a mistake in the fgetc loop

Comment: @Shawn instead of 'fgetc' or while adding the chars to the word[] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you drop the pointers ..

```
char ch;
char word[45];    
for (int i = 0; ;i++)
{
    ch = fgetc(ptr);
    word[i] = ch;
    if (ch == 10)
    {
        break;
    }
}
printf("%s\n", word);
```

Comment: thanks it worked now I can write loops to get all words

Comment: `printf("%s\n", word);` is writing `word` as a _string_, yet `word` lacks a _null character_.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it dynamically too :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./word filename\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *ptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    char *word = calloc(45, sizeof(char)); 
    for (ch = fgetc(ptr); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(ptr), i++)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            break;
        word[i] = ch;
    }
    printf("%s\n", word);
    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `char` is _unsigned_, `ch != EOF` is never true.  Best to use `int ch;` to well distinguish the typical 257 different values `fgetc()` returns.